# Ubunu Server Inherit directory permissions and ownership

Tags: linux, permissions, user-accounts, ubuntu-server

Before I begin, I apologize if this may seem as if it is a duplicate question, but no responses that I have found have been able to solve my problem.

I have a server setup running my company, with several users on the system.

When working with the website, all files need the permissions of `www-data`, however, when i create a file as `matt` or `taylor`, the files are always created with the users default permissions, so `matt:ceo` or `taylor:staff`. I need new files in the `www-data` directory to always inherit the permissions of `{user}:www-data` as well as have a default permission setting of 660.

In my current setup, I need to use sudo to chmod, and chown to correct everything.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the **setgid bit** for the `www-data` directory, all the files created under it will have the group set to that of the directory. The command to do this is:

```
chmod g+s www-data
```

Don't forget to add the users to the group that owns the directory, e.g.

```
usermod -a -G www-data matt
usermod -a -G www-data taylor
```

I don't know how you can set the default permission to 660 except using `umask` but that will apply to all files no matter where are created.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions can be inherited using *default ACLs*, if your filesystem supports them:

```
setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::- www-data
```